# If $P,Q$ are transition matrices of irreducible Markov Chains, what can you say about the stationary distribution of e.g. $\frac12(P+Q)$?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Assume that $P,Q\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ are stochastic matrices, and that the corresponding Markov Chains are irreducible. Let $\pi, \mu$ denote the respective stationary distributions.

If $\lambda\in(0,1)$, then $A_\lambda:=\lambda P+(1-\lambda)Q$ is clearly again a stochastic matrix, and the corresponding Markov Chain is again irreducible. Can we express its stationary distribution in terms of $\pi$ and $\mu$?

In general, it is quite difficult to say anything about the eigenvalues of the sum of matrices, as is discussed e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums). In this particular situation, though, we already know that 1 is a left eigenvalue of $A_\lambda$, and that the corresponding eigenspace has dimension one. Is there any way to make use of this and other properties of stochastic matrices in order to express its stationary distribution?